# Mnemonics not working in 18.04?

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts

When typing <kbd>Alt</kbd>, I do see the first letters underlined. (I cannot do screenshot to show it here with the underlines.)

[image]

But hitting <kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>V</kbd> etc. does not do anything.

I've tried adding `gnome-flashback` and also `unity`, like this:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-unity-desktop
```

They made no difference. What am I missing?

Comment: You experience this only for the terminal application, or also for other applications?

Comment: @vanadium Oh that's interesting:  `slack` *does* work.

Comment: Will very much depend on the application and on the toolkit that app uses. Test with a few apps and specify in your question (use "edit") where it works and where not. Implicitly indicate the desktop environment in which you are logged in when it happens.